# Cant do cd via Posh-SSH on a Linux remote

Tags: powershell, ssh, posh-ssh

I made a PowerShell script that connects to a linux pc using Posh-SSH. The script works fine but i found that i cant cd through directories for some reason.

This is how i pass the commands to Posh-SSH session:

```
$input = Read-Host "AutoSSH>"
$result = Invoke-SSHCommand -SessionId 0 -Command $input
$result.Output
```

The script is made so that SessionId 0 is the only possible active at the time and the $result just prints the output in a better way than Posh-SHH does. I have tried ls, service commands (like apache2 start/status), and more with expected results.

But when i try to cd it doesn't work. This is how i try and what i get in my tests:

```
Invoke-SSHCommand -SessionId 0 -Command "ls"

Host       : 192.168.xx.xxx
Output     : {asd.txt, Desktop, Documents, Downloads...}
ExitStatus : 0

Invoke-SSHCommand -SessionId 0 -Command "cd Desktop"

Host       : 192.168.xx.xxx
Output     : {}
ExitStatus : 0

Invoke-SSHCommand -SessionId 0 -Command "ls"

Host       : 192.168.xx.xxx
Output     : {asd.txt, Desktop, Documents, Downloads...}
ExitStatus : 0
```

I already read a lot of forums, Posh-SSH issues or docs with no answer to this problem.

why is this happening? Thanks

Comment: if you use cd instead of ls what happens? (https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000795.htm)

Comment: Passing the "cd" command gives me the same result shown in the post. Output     : {} ExitStatus : 0 . In all tests i also do a pwd but all results are /root (not moving to anywhere)

Comment: If you use `ls Desktop` what happens? And what about `cd  Desktop;ls` ?

Comment: ls Desktop gives the following output:
Output     : {mount-shared-folders.sh, restart-vm-tools.sh}
ExitStatus : 0

cd Desktop;ls: 
Output     : {mount-shared-folders.sh, restart-vm-tools.sh}
ExitStatus : 0

this results are interesting... maybe Posh-SSH resets to /root after a commands execution?

Comment: I can confirm from a test i made that i can navigate through directories and execute things perfectly but when the Invoke-SSHCommand ends the path comes back to /root. That's why i always get the same ls result.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the comments in the post and some testing i found this:

When i ran the commands, the cd was actually doing its job and that's why the command "cd Desktop; ls" displayed the correct info from the Desktop.

I found that the commands are always run in /root. Thus, "ls" was going to show the /root files every time, even if i pre-run a cd command in a different call.

Hope this info helps someone in the future!